# The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load

Tags: windows-10, dll, rewrite

I just upgraded to Windows 10 from 7. Cool so far, but when I try to go to any of my applications the app pool crashes and I get a 503. I can restart the app pool but it continues to crash. So I checked the event log to see what was happening. I then got the error "The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load". The problem most people had was that the dll was not there. However that is not my problem. Because it is there. After some googling I have not been able to find a solution. Can anyone please help me out? Accoding to my registry I am running IIS 10.0?

I have rewrite 2.0 installed. I was going to attempt this, http://forums.iis.net/t/1171695.aspx?How+do+I+determine+which+version+of+IIS+is+running (Change bit on Majorversion in registry and install rewrite 2.0)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ended up having to uninstall IIS Url Rewrite Module 2.0, then reinstalling. After the reinstall everything worked. I did not need to use the link in the question to reinstall.

Comment: This also worked after upgrading from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

Comment: Repair IIS URL rewrite + restart iis worked for me :)

Comment: Got the error "The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load" after upgrading Windows Server 2012 to 2016. Uninstalling "IIS Url Rewrite Module 2.0" from Programs and Features and reinstall from Microsoft website https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite + IISReset fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and reinstalling was not enough. Turns out my VM was way behind on windows update (probably a vanilla install without any updates...) and getting it up to then *then* reinstalling IIS URL Rewrite Module 2.0 fixed the issue.